# Distribution on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I have a serious question about the existence of a distribution.can anybody help me? Clearly I don't know whether any smooth manifold has a distribution? If not, why?

Answer (score 3):

A $k$-dimensional distribution on a smooth manifold $M$ is a subbundle $D$ of $TM$ of rank $k$. So every $n$-dimensional smooth manifold has a $0$-dimensional distribution (the image of the zero section) and an $n$-dimensional distribution, namely $D = TM$.

Depending on the manifold, these may be the only distributions. For example, a closed surface admits a $1$-dimensional distribution if and only if it has Euler characteristic zero. So $S^2$ for example does not admit any other distributions. More generally, the only distributions on $S^{2n}$ are the ones mentioned in the aforementioned paragraph. Both of these claims can be proved by using the multiplicativity of the Euler class.

Comment: Hi,you mean by considering zero vectors of a manifold one can define  a             0-dimensional distribution. Am I right? If yes, what does "the image" mean in your answer? Besides, I don't know what Euler characteristic means. Would you please explain more the second paragraph? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I mean the collection of zero vectors in the tangent spaces, i.e. $\{0_p \mid p \in M\}$ where $0_p \in T_pM$ is the zero vector. An alternative description of this subbundle is as the image of the map $p \mapsto 0_p$ which is a section of the natural projection $\pi : TM \to M$. The [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) is an elementary yet important notion in topology that every student of mathematics should learn, and for questions such as the one you asked, it plays an important role.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.